# How do I edit a cell in visual studio code interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In vscode you can use "Jupyter: Create interactive window" to create an interactive window that resembles jupyter notebook. However, in the interactive window I am unable to do a couple of things that I enjoy from jupyter notebook, such as editing a cell or moving the cells around. Is there any way to do these things inside an interactive window, without having to create an .ipynb file?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but: for editing you can use `# %%` to create 'cells' directly in the script you are working on. Then you can run the cells in the interactive window, this allows you to edit and re run. Explained in detail in the Jupyter code cells section from the [Python Interactive Window Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py).

[example from the Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW3YH.png)